# FFplay can't play facebook livestream

Tags: ffmpeg, facebook, dash

I try to play facebook livestream dash url I got from facebook with ffplay. However, I cannot play this stream.

Here is a sample playlist I got from facebook.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<MPD
  type="dynamic"
  xmlns="urn:mpeg:dash:schema:mpd:2011"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2011/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="urn:mpeg:DASH:schema:MPD:2011 DASH-MPD.xsd"
  profiles="urn:mpeg:dash:profile:isoff-live:2011"
  availabilityStartTime="2020-05-05T17:09:39-07:00"
  availabilityEndTime="2020-05-05T19:58:32-07:00"
  timeShiftBufferDepth="PT1M23S"
  suggestedPresentationDelay="PT2S"
  minBufferTime="PT1S"
  publishTime="2020-05-05T17:09:39-07:00"
  minimumUpdatePeriod="PT1S"
  FBMS="true"
  PTS="true"
  currentServerTimeMs="1588733414813"
  firstAvTimeMs="1588723771264"
  lastVideoFrameTs="9653205"
  loapStreamId="262304018486523"
  publishFrameTime="19085">
  <Period id="dash-abr5" start="PT0S">
    <AdaptationSet
      segmentAlignment="true"
      maxWidth="1920"
      maxHeight="1080"
      maxFrameRate="30">
      <Representation
        id="live-md-v"
        mimeType="video/mp4"
        codecs="avc1.4d401e"
        width="640"
        height="360"
        frameRate="30"
        startWithSAP="1"
        bandwidth="550000"
        FBQualityClass="sd"
        FBQualityLabel="360p">
        <SegmentTemplate
          presentationTimeOffset="0"
          timescale="1000"
          initialization="../live-md-v/262304018486523_0-init.m4v?ms=m_CN"
          media="../live-md-v/262304018486523_0-$Time$.m4v?ms=m_CN">
          <SegmentTimeline>
            <S t="9575906" d="8333"/>
            <S t="9584239" d="8334"/>
            <S t="9592573" d="8333"/>
            <S t="9600906" d="8333"/>
            <S t="9609239" d="8334"/>
            <S t="9617573" d="8333"/>
            <S t="9625906" d="8333"/>
            <S t="9634239" d="8334"/>
            <S t="9642573" d="8333"/>
            <S t="9650906" d="8333"/>
          </SegmentTimeline>
        </SegmentTemplate>
      </Representation>
      <Representation
        id="live-qd-v"
        mimeType="video/mp4"
        codecs="avc1.4d401e"
        width="256"
        height="144"
        frameRate="30"
        startWithSAP="1"
        bandwidth="110000"
        FBQualityClass="sd"
        FBQualityLabel="144p">
        <SegmentTemplate
          presentationTimeOffset="0"
          timescale="1000"
          initialization="../live-qd-v/262304018486523_0-init.m4v?ms=m_CN"
          media="../live-qd-v/262304018486523_0-$Time$.m4v?ms=m_CN">
          <SegmentTimeline>
            <S t="9575906" d="8333"/>
            <S t="9584239" d="8334"/>
            <S t="9592573" d="8333"/>
            <S t="9600906" d="8333"/>
            <S t="9609239" d="8334"/>
            <S t="9617573" d="8333"/>
            <S t="9625906" d="8333"/>
            <S t="9634239" d="8334"/>
            <S t="9642573" d="8333"/>
            <S t="9650906" d="8333"/>
          </SegmentTimeline>
        </SegmentTemplate>
      </Representation>
      <Representation
        id="live-ld-v"
        mimeType="video/mp4"
        codecs="avc1.4d401e"
        width="426"
        height="240"
        frameRate="30"
        startWithSAP="1"
        bandwidth="275000"
        FBQualityClass="sd"
        FBQualityLabel="240p">
        <SegmentTemplate
          presentationTimeOffset="0"
          timescale="1000"
          initialization="../live-ld-v/262304018486523_0-init.m4v?ms=m_CN"
          media="../live-ld-v/262304018486523_0-$Time$.m4v?ms=m_CN">
          <SegmentTimeline>
            <S t="9575906" d="8333"/>
            <S t="9584239" d="8334"/>
            <S t="9592573" d="8333"/>
            <S t="9600906" d="8333"/>
            <S t="9609239" d="8334"/>
            <S t="9617573" d="8333"/>
            <S t="9625906" d="8333"/>
            <S t="9634239" d="8334"/>
            <S t="9642573" d="8333"/>
            <S t="9650906" d="8333"/>
          </SegmentTimeline>
        </SegmentTemplate>
      </Representation>
      <Representation
        id="live-hd-v"
        mimeType="video/mp4"
        codecs="avc1.4d401e"
        width="854"
        height="480"
        frameRate="30"
        startWithSAP="1"
        bandwidth="1100000"
        FBQualityClass="sd"
        FBQualityLabel="480p">
        <SegmentTemplate
          presentationTimeOffset="0"
          timescale="1000"
          initialization="../live-hd-v/262304018486523_0-init.m4v?ms=m_CN"
          media="../live-hd-v/262304018486523_0-$Time$.m4v?ms=m_CN">
          <SegmentTimeline>
            <S t="9575906" d="8333"/>
            <S t="9584239" d="8334"/>
            <S t="9592573" d="8333"/>
            <S t="9600906" d="8333"/>
            <S t="9609239" d="8334"/>
            <S t="9617573" d="8333"/>
            <S t="9625906" d="8333"/>
            <S t="9634239" d="8334"/>
            <S t="9642573" d="8333"/>
            <S t="9650906" d="8333"/>
          </SegmentTimeline>
        </SegmentTemplate>
      </Representation>
      <Representation
        id="live-hd1-v"
        mimeType="video/mp4"
        codecs="avc1.4d401e"
        width="1280"
        height="720"
        frameRate="30"
        startWithSAP="1"
        bandwidth="2200000"
        FBQualityClass="hd"
        FBQualityLabel="720p">
        <SegmentTemplate
          presentationTimeOffset="0"
          timescale="1000"
          initialization="../live-hd1-v/262304018486523_0-init.m4v?ms=m_CN"
          media="../live-hd1-v/262304018486523_0-$Time$.m4v?ms=m_CN">
          <SegmentTimeline>
            <S t="9575906" d="8333"/>
            <S t="9584239" d="8334"/>
            <S t="9592573" d="8333"/>
            <S t="9600906" d="8333"/>
            <S t="9609239" d="8334"/>
            <S t="9617573" d="8333"/>
            <S t="9625906" d="8333"/>
            <S t="9634239" d="8334"/>
            <S t="9642573" d="8333"/>
            <S t="9650906" d="8333"/>
          </SegmentTimeline>
        </SegmentTemplate>
      </Representation>
      <Representation
        id="live-hd2-v"
        mimeType="video/mp4"
        codecs="avc1.4d401e"
        width="1920"
        height="1080"
        frameRate="30"
        startWithSAP="1"
        bandwidth="3850000"
        FBQualityClass="hd"
        FBQualityLabel="1080p">
        <SegmentTemplate
          presentationTimeOffset="0"
          timescale="1000"
          initialization="../live-hd2-v/262304018486523_0-init.m4v?ms=m_CN"
          media="../live-hd2-v/262304018486523_0-$Time$.m4v?ms=m_CN">
          <SegmentTimeline>
            <S t="9575906" d="8333"/>
            <S t="9584239" d="8334"/>
            <S t="9592573" d="8333"/>
            <S t="9600906" d="8333"/>
            <S t="9609239" d="8334"/>
            <S t="9617573" d="8333"/>
            <S t="9625906" d="8333"/>
            <S t="9634239" d="8334"/>
            <S t="9642573" d="8333"/>
            <S t="9650906" d="8333"/>
          </SegmentTimeline>
        </SegmentTemplate>
      </Representation>
      <Representation
        id="live-pst-v"
        mimeType="video/mp4"
        codecs="avc1.4d401e"
        width="1920"
        height="1080"
        frameRate="30"
        startWithSAP="1"
        bandwidth="15000000"
        FBQualityClass="hd"
        FBQualityLabel="1080p (Source)">
        <SegmentTemplate
          presentationTimeOffset="0"
          timescale="1000"
          initialization="../live-pst-v/262304018486523_0-init.m4v?ms=m_CN"
          media="../live-pst-v/262304018486523_0-$Time$.m4v?ms=m_CN">
          <SegmentTimeline>
            <S t="9575906" d="8333"/>
            <S t="9584239" d="8334"/>
            <S t="9592573" d="8333"/>
            <S t="9600906" d="8333"/>
            <S t="9609239" d="8334"/>
            <S t="9617573" d="8333"/>
            <S t="9625906" d="8333"/>
            <S t="9634239" d="8334"/>
            <S t="9642573" d="8333"/>
            <S t="9650906" d="8333"/>
          </SegmentTimeline>
        </SegmentTemplate>
      </Representation>
    </AdaptationSet>
    <AdaptationSet segmentAlignment="true">
      <Representation
        id="live-md-a"
        mimeType="audio/mp4"
        codecs="mp4a.40.2"
        audioSamplingRate="48000"
        startWithSAP="1"
        bandwidth="65698">
        <SegmentTemplate
          presentationTimeOffset="0"
          timescale="1000"
          initialization="../live-md-a/262304018486523_0-init.m4a?ms=m_CN"
          media="../live-md-a/262304018486523_0-$Time$.m4a?ms=m_CN">
          <SegmentTimeline>
            <S t="9575906" d="8333"/>
            <S t="9584239" d="8334"/>
            <S t="9592573" d="8333"/>
            <S t="9600906" d="8333"/>
            <S t="9609239" d="8334"/>
            <S t="9617573" d="8333"/>
            <S t="9625906" d="8333"/>
            <S t="9634239" d="8334"/>
            <S t="9642573" d="8333"/>
            <S t="9650906" d="8333"/>
          </SegmentTimeline>
        </SegmentTemplate>
      </Representation>
    </AdaptationSet>
  </Period>
</MPD>
```

Here is the output from ffplay

```
ffplay version 4.2.2-1ubuntu1~18.04.york0 Copyright (c) 2003-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7 (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version='1ubuntu1~18.04.york0' --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --arch=amd64 --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --disable-filter=resample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opencl --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-nvenc --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      56. 31.100 / 56. 31.100
  libavcodec     58. 54.100 / 58. 54.100
  libavformat    58. 29.100 / 58. 29.100
  libavdevice    58.  8.100 / 58.  8.100
  libavfilter     7. 57.100 /  7. 57.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  5.100 /  5.  5.100
  libswresample   3.  5.100 /  3.  5.100
  libpostproc    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
https://video.fhan2-4.fna.fbcdn.net/hvideo-frc3-ftw/_nc_cat-109/v/rTsIPYF6kXwgjvEukHmUC/live-dash/dash-abr5/262304018486523.mpd?_nc_rl=AfAqK1YETG74Qoqr&ms=m_CN&oh=8acc3faf91ca83b70c19b74c233a3864&oe=5EB3A3B3:248: parser error : Specification mandate value for attribute presentationTim
          presentationTim
                         ^
https://video.fhan2-4.fna.fbcdn.net/hvideo-frc3-ftw/_nc_cat-109/v/rTsIPYF6kXwgjvEukHmUC/live-dash/dash-abr5/262304018486523.mpd?_nc_rl=AfAqK1YETG74Qoqr&ms=m_CN&oh=8acc3faf91ca83b70c19b74c233a3864&oe=5EB3A3B3:248: parser error : attributes construct error
          presentationTim
                         ^
https://video.fhan2-4.fna.fbcdn.net/hvideo-frc3-ftw/_nc_cat-109/v/rTsIPYF6kXwgjvEukHmUC/live-dash/dash-abr5/262304018486523.mpd?_nc_rl=AfAqK1YETG74Qoqr&ms=m_CN&oh=8acc3faf91ca83b70c19b74c233a3864&oe=5EB3A3B3:248: parser error : Couldn't find end of Start Tag SegmentTemplate line 247
          presentationTim
                         ^
https://video.fhan2-4.fna.fbcdn.net/hvideo-frc3-ftw/_nc_cat-109/v/rTsIPYF6kXwgjvEukHmUC/live-dash/dash-abr5/262304018486523.mpd?_nc_rl=AfAqK1YETG74Qoqr&ms=m_CN&oh=8acc3faf91ca83b70c19b74c233a3864&oe=5EB3A3B3:248: parser error : Premature end of data in tag Representation line 240
          presentationTim
                         ^
https://video.fhan2-4.fna.fbcdn.net/hvideo-frc3-ftw/_nc_cat-109/v/rTsIPYF6kXwgjvEukHmUC/live-dash/dash-abr5/262304018486523.mpd?_nc_rl=AfAqK1YETG74Qoqr&ms=m_CN&oh=8acc3faf91ca83b70c19b74c233a3864&oe=5EB3A3B3:248: parser error : Premature end of data in tag AdaptationSet line 239
          presentationTim
                         ^
https://video.fhan2-4.fna.fbcdn.net/hvideo-frc3-ftw/_nc_cat-109/v/rTsIPYF6kXwgjvEukHmUC/live-dash/dash-abr5/262304018486523.mpd?_nc_rl=AfAqK1YETG74Qoqr&ms=m_CN&oh=8acc3faf91ca83b70c19b74c233a3864&oe=5EB3A3B3:248: parser error : Premature end of data in tag Period line 22
          presentationTim
                         ^
https://video.fhan2-4.fna.fbcdn.net/hvideo-frc3-ftw/_nc_cat-109/v/rTsIPYF6kXwgjvEukHmUC/live-dash/dash-abr5/262304018486523.mpd?_nc_rl=AfAqK1YETG74Qoqr&ms=m_CN&oh=8acc3faf91ca83b70c19b74c233a3864&oe=5EB3A3B3:248: parser error : Premature end of data in tag MPD line 2
          presentationTim
                         ^
[dash @ 0x7fd21c000b80] Unable to parse 'https://video.fhan2-4.fna.fbcdn.net/hvideo-frc3-ftw/_nc_cat-109/v/rTsIPYF6kXwgjvEukHmUC/live-dash/dash-abr5/262304018486523.mpd?_nc_rl=AfAqK1YETG74Qoqr&ms=m_CN&oh=8acc3faf91ca83b70c19b74c233a3864&oe=5EB3A3B3' - missing root node
https://video.fhan2-4.fna.fbcdn.net/hvideo-frc3-ftw/_nc_cat-109/v/rTsIPYF6kXwgjvEukHmUC/live-dash/dash-abr5/262304018486523.mpd?_nc_rl=AfAqK1YETG74Qoqr&ms=m_CN&oh=8acc3faf91ca83b70c19b74c233a3864&oe=5EB3A3B3: Invalid data found when processing input
```

It's weird that ffplay can't parse the master playlist. I use latest ffmpeg version 4.2.2. 
I also try to play this url with vlc, it works well.
Does anyone is familiar with this problem ?

Thanks.